# app is not working after it's been terminated by app switcher

Tags: android, react-native

I have developed react-native android app. when i opened the app for the first time everything is ok and working as expected. Then i terminated my app by using app switcher then opened app once again. This time one white blank screen came and nothing happens from there. I have a console log in constructor in root file if the app and i didn't find this log in studio when i run the app. So, it's clear that constructor hasn't been called and this is where where i got struct.

Since I am not android developer I don't know how to debug this issue. Can someone help me to solve this?

**Edit**: This is happening only in release mode. Debug mode is working fine

Thank You.

Comment: metro bundler is running ? you try uninstall the app and start again ?

Comment: You can try logcat and check if that logged any error

Comment: @anthonywillismuñozI tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no use. BTW it's happening only in release mode debug mode is fine

Answer (score 0):

Move `console.log` from constructor to componentDidMount.
Constructer is not called opening by switcher.

Comment: OP have terminated the screen from app switcher so there is no way to open it from app switcher.

Comment: @SaachiTechYes you are right. I have opened app by tapping on the app icon